# ExpressJs: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory

Tags: javascript, express

I am trying to add hbs template in my code but I am getting the errror that Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory

```
const express = require("express")
const path = require("path")
require("../src/db/conn")

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const static_path = path.join(__dirname, "../public")

app.use(express.static(static_path))
app.set("view engine" , "hbs");


app.get("/" , (req,res)=>{
    res.render("index")
})

app.listen(port , ()=>{
    console.log("server is listening on port no 3000" )
})
```

this is my code and also i have created a **views** folder and a **index.hbs** file inside that folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.set("view engine" , "hbs");
```

After this line add

```
app.set("views" , "views");
```